# Bidirectional one to one mapping in GAE using JDO?

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

How can I implement a bidirectional one-to-one mapping using `Google Application Engine` (`GAE`) using `Java Data Objects` (`JDO`)?

I have a `User` class which holds `contactInfo` object and a `ContactInfo` class that holds a `user` object

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType ="APPLICATION", detachable = "true")
public class User{
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Persistent(dependent = "true")
  private ContactInfo child;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public ContactInfo getChild() {
    return child;
  }

  public void setChild(ContactInfo child) {
    this.child = child;
  }
}


@PersistenceCapable(identityType ="APPLICATION", detachable = "true")
public class ContactInfo {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  @Persistent(mappedBy = "child")
  private User parent;

  private String contactDetail;

  public Key getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Key id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getContactDetail() {
    return contactDetail;
  }

  public void setContactDetail(String contactDetail) {
    this.contactDetail = contactDetail;
  }
}
```

Following error i am getting while testing API from API explorer

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.demo.jdo.ContactInfo[\"user\"]-&gt;com.demo.jdo.User[\"contactInfo\"]-&gt;com.demo.jdo.ContactInfo[\"user\"]-
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard JDO 1-1 bidir is simply found from http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/orm/one_to_one.html#bi
GAE ought to be no different in this respect; last time I used it (maybe 3 yrs ago) they had some tests, think those under here http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus

Your question provides no definition of what you have tried in terms of annotations

Comment: Why have you put "mappedBy" at both ends? One end only

Comment: Which end i should put? and apart from it whats wrong with the code??

Comment: On the non-owner side. The provided links explain that.

Comment: Thanks Billy, found solution posted above as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution, problem was with wrong use of mappedBy & presence of getter and setter of parent object in child.

- @Persistent(mappedBy = "") annotation should only be at non-owner side
- In on-owner/ child side there should not be any getter/setter present for owner/parent object.

Working code:

**User.java**

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class User {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;

@Persistent(dependent = "true")
private ContactInfo contactInfo;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ContactInfo getContactInfo() {
    return contactInfo;
}

public void setContactInfo(ContactInfo contactInfo) {
    this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
}
}
```

**ContactInfo.java**

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class ContactInfo {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "contactInfo")
    /*
     * Important: Do not create getter and setters for this object else
     * bidirectional mapping gives error
     */
    private User user;

    private String contactDetail;

    public Key getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Key id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContactDetail() {
        return contactDetail;
    }

    public void setContactDetail(String contactDetail) {
        this.contactDetail = contactDetail;
    }
}
```